# How can I save the RVIZ visualization to an image file

Tags: ros, visualization, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am publishing data trough different publisher, mainly with visualization_msgs::Marker and  nav_msgs::GridCells objects.
I get a visualization in my RVIZ window and what I want to do is to save this visualization into an image of the size I want.

Do you know if there is a plug-in who can do that ? Or if there is some other way to do that ?

I don't want to do a screen shot because i would like the size of my image to be bigger than the actual definition of my screen.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296877/how-can-i-save-the-rviz-visualization-to-an-image-file/) by [antoineniotna](https://answers.ros.org/users/34023/antoineniotna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at #q142351 and #q258251 - rviz_camera_stream should do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1